# Universal property is equivalent to couniversal property

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ be two categories and
$$F\colon \mathcal C\to\mathcal D\qquad U\colon\mathcal D\to\mathcal C$$
two functors. For each $X\in\mathcal C$, let $\eta_X\colon X\to UFX$. Suppose that for all $X\in\mathcal C$ and $Y\in\mathcal D$,
$$\Phi_{X,Y}\colon \hom(FX,Y)\to \hom(X,UY),\qquad f\mapsto U(f)\circ\eta_X$$
is a bijection.

For $Y\in\mathcal D$ let $\varepsilon_Y\colon FUY\to Y$ be such that $\Phi^{-1}_{UY,Y}(f)=U(\varepsilon_Y)\circ\eta_{UY}=\mathrm{id}_{UY}$, which exists by the above assumption.

**Question:** How can one, in an elementary way (without knowing other facts about adjunctions), show that $$\Psi_{X,Y}\colon \hom(X,UY)\to \hom(FX,Y),\qquad g\mapsto \varepsilon_Y\circ F(g)$$
is the inverse of $\Phi_{X,Y}$?

Here is an observation: it suffices to show that
$$U(\varepsilon_Y\circ F(g))\circ\eta_X=g\qquad (\ast)$$
for all $g\colon X\to UY$.

But there are no assumptions one could obviously exploit to get $(\ast)$.

Comment: Don't you suppose that the $η_X$ are natural in $X$? If you don't suppose that, you cannot show what you want (and if you do, the easiest way I see is to extract your proof from the proofs of the "other facts about adjunctions"). The natural isomorphism $\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}\Hom(FX,Y) ≅ \Hom(X,UY)$ determines the functoriality of $F$ and if it's not natural, you could have another $F'$ which agrees with $F$ on objects but not on morphisms, and which is the one making the isomorphism natural in $X$. I can show you an example if you want.

Comment: @Idéophage Thanks, I see! I should have added the assumption that $F$ is given on morphisms by assigning to each $f\colon X\to Y$ in $\mathcal C$ the morphism $\Phi^{-1}(\eta_Y\circ f)\colon FX\to FY$. I wonder: what's so hard about giving a direct proof of the fact I want to prove? Which "other facts about adjunctions" would you use?

Comment: Ah, so did you try to replace $F(g)$ in the equation you're trying to prove with your definition of $F(g)$? I don't know if there is something more to do but you can always try.

Comment: Yup, checked it myself. This is enlightening, thank you. :)